# How can i bind string return from ajax call with v-html in v-for in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2

i want to bind v-html with string returning from ajax call in v-for.

```
<div v-for="row in data">
  <div v-html="getHtml[row.id]"></div>
```

```
//fun
getHtml(i){
 this.$http.get('.....').then((data) => return data.html;)
}
```

Comment: You should store responded data from API into the `data` object and then you can pass HTML via `v-html` directive.

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like this:

> ## @Template

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-html="newContent"></div>
</div>
```

> ## @Vue instance

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app"
    data: {
        newContent: ''
    },
    mounted: function() {
        var that = this;
        this.$http.get(ENDPOINT)
            .then(function(data) { that.newContent = data })
            .catch(function(error) { console.log(error); });
    }
});
```

---

## What is happening?

At this example we are binding a data property `newContent` to a div using the `v-html` directive.
What this means is that everytime that property changes the `div` content will be updated.

After the component gets `mounted` it will fire an AJAX request `.then()` it will assign the response data to the `newContent` property, which as we seen before will automatically update the view due to its reactivity.

Comment: I am using Vuejs 2 with es2015 in my webpack template. so do i need to create component first then need to import in main file?
And then i need to use template in v-for?
i am new to vuejs

Comment: If you're using a `.vue` file just define the template and the script in the same file.